# Does DC quiescent current vary with the load applied in an amplifier?

Tags: operational-amplifier, current, amplifier, quiescent

can you please clarify why the DC quiescent current in an opamp should decrease with load applied?

Is it just a Spice model semplification or is there intrinsic cause?

To me the DC quiescent current (here 6.4 mA, quite correct as per datasheet) need to bias the class AB power stage of the op-amplifier and should stay constant (and not decrease to a min of 4mA) with load applied.

[image]

Comment: If you look closely, you'll see that when the input signal is at \$0\:\text{V}\$ on your left-side opamp, that the supply currents are both close to \$6\:\text{mA}\$ and exactly the same as in the right-side opamp.

Comment: A class-AB output is composed of two quadrants, where the biasing has both of them slightly ON at this midpoint. However, when one of the quadrants is more fully ON, the other quadrant is slightly more fully OFF, too. It's pretty obvious why a class-AB would behave like this given that each quadrant operates for a little more than \$180^\circ\$.

Comment: Sorry but this doesn't explain to me the 4mA instead of 6mA

Comment: It was just a comment hoping that would be enough. It was not a detailed explanation. If I did that, I would have written an answer, instead. I take it you've never examined or performed a class-AB design, then. You say it should stay constant as though you know something. I was just saying that's wrong.

Comment: Invert your dark blue curve so that it overlaps your green curve. Add a plot of your sinusoidal input voltage source. Use the cursors available on the plot screen and locate the place where your input source is exactly zero volts. Read off the supply currents on the left side opamp to yourself. Compare them to the right side opamp currents. You'll see they are the same. Then zoom in on that transition region and study it more carefully. See if you can arrive at an understanding, thinking about what is actually going on here. If you know how class-AB works, you'll easily have your answer.